# rspec raise_on_type_mismatch for integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

A student (`User`) can take an appointment with a mentor (`User`). With rspec I want to test that the `mentor.id` is the expected one in the `Appointment` created. But I'm getting a type mismatch.

```
-> % rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
`raise_on_type_mismatch!': Course(#141481930) expected, got Fixnum(#77638390) (ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch)
from /home/guinsly/totrash/startup_mentors2/spec/models/user_spec.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

the line 69 correspond in the `user_spec.rb` to the line starting with `Appointment.create`

spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
  context '#Appointment' do 
    mentor = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    student = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    course = FactoryGirl.create(:course)
    mentor.courses << course
    mentor.save!

    Appointment.create(
      :mentor_id => mentor.id, 
      :student_id => student.id,
      :course => course.id 
      :day_rdv => 1.day.from_now)
    rdv = Appointment.last

    it 'should have the first mentor (id: 1) ' do
      expect(rdv.mentor.id).to eq mentor.id
    end
  end
```

appointment.rb

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :mentor, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: "mentor_id"
  belongs_to :student, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: "student_id"
end
```

migration

```
class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :appointments, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :mentor_id, null: false
      t.integer :student_id, null: false
      t.integer :course_id, null: false
      t.datetime :day_rdv, null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :appointments, :mentor_id
    add_index :appointments, :student_id
    add_index :appointments, :course_id
  end
end
```

factories

users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email Faker::Internet.email
    password 'password'
    password_confirmation 'password'
    # required if the Devise Confirmable module is used
    #confirmed_at Time.now
  end
end
```

courses.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :course do
    name Faker::Lorem.word.to_s
    bio Faker::Lorem.paragraph(2).to_s
    price Faker::Number.decimal(2).to_f
    nb_hours "2"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with this line:

```
course => course.id
```

You are creating an Appointment object whose course field must be assigned a Course object. But you give it the course id instead. Hence the error message:

```
`raise_on_type_mismatch!': Course(#141481930) expected, got Fixnum(#77638390)
```

It was expected to be assigned a Course object and got a Fixnum which is your course.id